# Best way to store intrinsic camera parameters on Android

Tags: android, opencv

I am having some troubles saving the camera intrinsics to the sd card.
The camera calibration is working, but I need to store the intrinsics to the sd card and load them back when the app restarts. 
This is a problem for me, can someone help me and provide me some information about how to store the intrinics, as the save xml stuff from openCV seems not to be available on android.

Thanks

PS my intrinsics are store in a Mat

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21922685/1085483

Comment: @glethien can you please help me on how to calculate intrinsic matrix from image captured from camera ?