# Export to file. Txt from screens android

Tags: android, opencv

I do not speak English well so I need the help of http://translate.google.com What words should not expect people to ignore good 
Currently I am working on android project as voice recognition and display the results on the phone screen. From the results I show I want to export it to a file. Txt or any file for transmission. I know the OpenCV library but I'm having trouble not know how to start. I expect people to give their opinions. Thank you very much.

`Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");`

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_SPEECH) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
            ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            tvkq.setText(text.get(0));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21922685/1085483. It will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the Android OpenCV binary have data persistence functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590481/does-the-android-opencv-binary-have-data-persistence-functions)

Comment: thank you :)
I have handled the problem without using the opencv. I allow access to the user's phone memory card to create a text file through 1 1 TextView I have previously